# Are Work Item IDs unique in TFS, even when using multiple projects?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

This feels more like an 'English' question than a 'Stack Overflow' question, but I'm about to commit to a data structure that will be very hard to change later, so I wanted to be *absolutely* sure about this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/titles-ids-descriptions?view=azure-devops

This documentation states that the ID field of a Work Item is unique across *all* projects and *within* a project collection. If I am reading that correctly, this means that once a Work Item of any type - User Story, Ticket, Data Fix, Bug, Code, whatever - has been created inside one project with one ID, then no other project on the same TFS server will ever use the same ID number for a work item of *any* type, in *any* project? Even once a Work Item has been closed - possibly deleted - the same ID number will never be reused?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/about-work-items?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=agile-process#work-item-form),we can confirm that **work item ID is unique identifier which is assigned by system**.

[image]

We can also certify this by testing. We create a task item in project 1, the assigned id is #210, then we create another same item in project ed, and the assigned id is #211. It can be seen that the id assigned by the system is incremented in order.

[image]
[image]

Then we delete the item with id #211, and then create a new item in project1. The newly created item has an id of #212. It can be seen from this that the id of the deleted item is not reused.

[image]

In summary,it can be sure that Work Item IDs are unique across all projects. You don't worry that work items with the same id appear in different projects.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You read it right. Work item IDs are unique for a collection though you delete/destroy one.